# How can I rewind an AWS glue job bookmark using the AWS CLI or boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, aws-glue

What I am looking for is way to programmatically or from the command line do the same thing as the `Rewind job bookmark` button in the AWS Glue Console does.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it programmatically right now (it might be in the future)

A solution right now can be:

If you are extracting AWS S3 files into your job and transforming them:

- You can create a function that picks the files you want to reprocess so it moves them to the same folder.

If you are using `--from-date` and `--to-date` you can set them to the value you want.